# How to repaint with timer?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I want to provide a projectile motion with timer. First of all I create timer and I change the location of x and y with timer. When I check that all X and Y points are updated but I can not repaint new X and Y. How to repaint my panel and provide the projectile motion? Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Deneme extends JPanel {

    double positionY = 100;
    double positionX = 100;
    double velocityY = 20;
    double velocityX = 20;
    double acceleration = -10;
    Timer timer;

    public Deneme() {
        timer = new Timer(100, new myTimerListener());
    }

    private class myTimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            update(0.09);
            repaint();
        }

    }

    void update(double dt) {
        positionX += velocityX * dt;
        positionY += velocityY * dt + acceleration * 0.5 * dt * dt;
        velocityY += acceleration * dt;
        System.out.println(positionX + " " + positionY);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawOval((int) positionX, (int) positionY, 15, 15);
    }

    public double positionY() {
        return positionY;
    }

    public double velocityY() {
        return velocityY;
    }

    public double positionX() {
        return positionX;
    }

    public double velocityX() {
        return velocityX;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Deneme().timer.start();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Basketball");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1500, 1000);
        frame.add(new Deneme());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong Timer. This is a Swing GUI, and so all repeated code should be done using a `javax.swing.Timer` or "Swing" Timer.

Comment: **Also**: never have a Graphics field as your program has as that's an invitation to disaster and **never** call `repaint()` from within a painting method as that leads to a completely uncontrolled animation.

Comment: I got it. thank you so much